# ¿Cómo se genera un listado csv a partir de una lista Get-ChildItem de PowerShell desde VBA?

Tags: vba, powershell

Estoy intentando hacer una macro en vba que sea capaz de hacer una lista en csv de todos los archivos de una carpeta y todas sus subcarpetas, utilizando para ello el commando Get-ChildItem del PowerShell.

Desde la ventana de PowerShell puedo hacerlo sin problemas utilizando el siguiente comando:

```
gci "C:\Users\u36557\Desktop\Primera Prueba" -rec -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select-object Attributes, Fullname, Name, Extension, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime, Length | export-csv "C:\Users\u36557\Desktop\Primera Prueba\listado.csv" -notypeinformation -delimiter ";"
```

Sin embargo no logro ejecutar lo mismo desde vba. Lo más cerca que creo haberme quedado es como pongo a continuación:

```
Sub LanzarComandoPS()
    Ruta = "C:\Users\u36557\Desktop\Primera Prueba"
    Comando = "powershell command ""{gci """ & Ruta & """ -rec -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | " & _
    "select-object Attributes, Fullname, Name, Extension, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime, Length | " & _
    "export-csv """ & Ruta & "\listado.csv"" -notypeinformation -delimiter "";""}"""
    Lanzamiento = Shell(Comando, vbMaximizedFocus)
End Sub
```

Con ese código creo ver (porque pasa muy rápido) que se construye el listado, sin embargo no funciona la parte en la que se genera el csv con el comando "export-csv".

¿Hay alguien que sepa cómo puedo corregir mi código vba para que se genere el archivo csv con el listado especificado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor para encapsular una cadena de texto con espacios para ejecutarlo en PowerShell es el apóstrofe, el símbolo ***'***.

```
Sub LanzarComandoPS()
    Ruta = "C:\Users\u36557\Desktop\Primera Prueba"
    NombreListado = "\Listar Archivos Aux1.csv"
    Programa = "PowerShell -Command "
    Accion = "Get-ChildItem "
    Opciones = " -rec -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue"
    Grabador = "Export-Csv "

    CM2 = """" ' para encapsular el texto de manera literal
    CM3 = "'" 'para encapsular el texto

    OpcionesCSV = " -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter " & CM3 & ";" & CM3
    Separador = " | "
    Columnas = "select-object " & _
        "Attributes, " & _
        "Fullname, " & _
        "Name, " & _
        "Extension, " & _
        "CreationTime, " & _
        "LastAccessTime, " & _
        "LastWriteTime, " & _
        "Length"
    Comando = Programa & Accion & CM3 & CM2 & Ruta & CM2 & CM3 & Opciones & _
              Separador & Columnas & Separador & Grabador & _
              CM3 & CM2 & Ruta & NombreListado & CM2 & CM3 & OpcionesCSV
    VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run Comando, 2, True
End Sub
```

Sinembargo también es posible hacerlo con comillas pero teniendo en cuenta lo que dice la respuesta anterior.

Además, al enviar cadenas de texto desde vba a PowerShell, los dobles espacios se transforman en uno solo. Para evitarlo se debe encapsular además entre comillas:

```
VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "PowerShell -NoExit -Command cd '""C:\Users\u36557\Doble  espacio""'", 2, True
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo hice algo similar y lo que me daba problemas eran las comillas, prueba a crear una variable comillas para encerrar las rutas, o puedes crear el script en un archivo aparte y ejecutarlo con wsh.
**Ejemplo**

```
    'Crear el objeto shell que ejecutara el script PowerShell
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 2
    Dim Comillas As String
    Comillas = """"
    ' Ejecutar el script PowerShell
    wsh.Run "powershell -File " & Comillas & Script & Comillas & " " & Comillas & Ruta & Comillas, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

Comment: El tema es que quiero evitar tener que crear un archivo solo para lanzarlo. De todas formas he intentado hacer lo mismo con wsh.Run y el efecto es exactamente el mismo. Estoy probando un montón de combinaciones a ver si lo consigo. Estoy casi seguro de que es lo que dices de las comillas,,, pero es que hasta que de con la tecla... XD

Comment: Toda la culpa la tienen los espacios en la ruta

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he dado con la combinación de comillas, ¡y son muchas! El caso es que como las rutas en las que está mirando tiene espacios, deben meterse entre comillas triples antes de lanzarlo a PowerShell para que se conviertan en una sola. Además las comillas en VBA necesitan más comillas XD

```
Sub LanzarComandoPSf()
    Ruta = "D:\Windows\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (3)"
    Comando = "powershell -Command ""gci """"""" & Ruta & """"""" -rec -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | " & _
              "select-object Attributes, Fullname, " & "Name, Extension, CreatmionTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime, Length | " & _
              "export-csv """"""" & Ruta & "\listado.csv" & """"" -notypeinformation -delimiter """""";"""""""""
    Lanzamiento = Shell(Comando, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Me explico mejor: Al querer introducir una comilla en una variable tipo String en vba, hay que escribir dos comillas para que vba lo interprete como texto en lugar que encapsulado. Como para definir una variable String hacen falta otras dos comillas, de esta forma hacen falta cuatro comillas para tener una sola.

Posteriormente, al utilizar 'Shell' o 'Run' ocurre nuevamente lo mismo con el 'PathName', o lo que yo he llamado en mi macro 'Comando', por lo tanto hay que poner muuuuchas comillas XD

Se reduce la cantidad de comillas necesarias si se hace lo de la variable comillas, ya sea utilizando """" o Chr(34)

Pongo a continuación el código un poco más limpio para que se vea que es cada cosa, aunque ahora ocupa más espacio. También incluyo la opción de @Edwin.

```
Sub LanzarComandoPS()
    Ruta = "D:\Windows\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (3)"
    NombreListado = "\listado.csv"
    Programa = "PowerShell"
    Accion = " -Command "
    Comando = "Get-ChildItem "
    Opciones = " -rec -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue"
    Grabador = "Export-Csv "
    OpcionesCSV = " -notypeinformation -delimiter "
    Delimitador = ";"
    Separador = " | "
    CM3 = """"""
    Atributos = "select-object " & _
        "Attributes, " & _
        "Fullname, " & _
        "Name, " & _
        "Extension, " & _
        "CreatmionTime, " & _
        "LastAccessTime, " & _
        "LastWriteTime, " & _
        "Length"
    Comando = Programa & Accion & Comando & CM3 & Ruta & CM3 & _
              Opciones & Separador & Atributos & Separador & Grabador & CM3 & Ruta & _
              NombreListado & CM3 & OpcionesCSV & CM3 & Delimitador & CM3
    ' OPCION 1
    Lanzamiento = Shell(Comando, vbNormalFocus)
    ' OPCION 2
    VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run Comando, 2, True
End Sub
```

Se puede explicar un poco mejor: 
Cuando se quiere introducir una instrucción en PowerShell que incluya una cadena de texto con espacios, es necesario introducir esta cadena de texto entre comillas para que sea identificado como un único elemento:

```
Get-ChildItem -rec "C:\users\juanito\Desktop\Primera prueba").count
```

Cuando se envía una instrucción a PowerShell desde VBA que incluya alguna cadena de texto con comillas, para que el carácter comillas sea identificado como tal, es necesario encapsularlas dentro de otras comillas:

```
Get-ChildItem -rec """C:\users\juanito\Desktop\Primera prueba""").count
```

Finalmente, cuando en VBA se quiere almacenar un texto en una variable tipo String, el símbolo comillas hay que escribirlo dos veces por cada vez que queremos una sola:

```
Get-ChildItem -rec """"""C:\users\juanito\Desktop\Primera prueba"""""").count
```